# Upload media to Firebase Storage from Standalone Apple Watch app

Tags: swift, firebase, rest, firebase-storage, watch

I'm trying to create an apple watch only app besides our app. This would be a standalone app without ties to the base app.

I can't use Firebase SDK-s, or other Google SDK-s as none of them support the watch.

I am trying to use the REST API-s and I hit a road block.

I can successfully retrieve a token for a user/password account with the identitytoolkit domain "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key="

which gives me a token I am trying to use for the endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/mybucketid/o?uploadType=media&name=test233

however this endpoint tells me that I'm unauthorized. When I use the token I get with from OAuth 2.0 playground it works.

The problem is that that one expires and I cant build the app with a new token every time obviously.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't open webviews on the watch to approve a sign in, also can't communicate with an iPhone as this is a standalone app. I need something thats just hardcoded pure code. This is still an experiment and wont go out to real users. A non-expiring token would also work for my use-case.

I changed my buckets policy in a way that my user should be able to  write into it but its still giving me authorization issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upload to a Cloud Storage bucket that is secured by Firebase through the REST API with a Firebase Authentication user. Essentially the REST API doesn't know how to execute Firebase rules, and only accepts operations that come with an OAuth2 token from a collaborator on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you authenticate with the iPhone app and get a token from there when the old one expires? I know you are building a standalone watch app, but maybe this is a compromise worth making. Then you could use Firebase Functions to upload the image, validate the token (admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)) and push the image to Cloud Storage. I have not tried this with an image but have successfully submitted authenticated payloads to the Firebase Realtime Database REST endpoints from a watchKit app.